# JSF e-commerce application with objects coming from Restful web service

Tags: web-services, rest, jsf-2, e-commerce

I want to build an e-commerce application using JSF 2.0. I saw some examples (including the ones that come bundled with NetBeans). In those examples data was stored in some sort of database and was retrieved and queried using SQL. In those examples there was some sort of persistent object in the application. What I want to do is retrieve data from a Restful Web Service and so I will not use SQL at all. My question is: Do I need to include a model section (MVC pattern) in my application having persistent objects or should I just use beans which will directly connect with the web service? How does such an application generally work?

Answer (score 1):

Your REST service would provide some data (JSON, XML), probably it would be handy to map these data to model classes on JSF application side. So in your JSF bean you would connect REST service, map data obtained from it to model classes and then call some bussines logic (that use model classes).

Obviously if the REST service returns single number or string there is no use to create another class just for the sake of architecture. Similarly if you bussiness logic is very simple, it is better to do everything in JSF managed bean class.